# Confuse about Ionic official and Ionic.io

Tags: ionic-framework

All:

I am trying to figure out what is the relationship between Ionic official site( http://ionicframework.com/ ) and Ionic.io, are they belong to same company and ionic.io is just a service for ionic?

Or they are basically irrelevant?

The reason I ask this question is I find that Ionic.io is going to charge potentially( http://ionic.io/pricing ) which may affect my future decision about which mobile framework to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic, the framework (ionicframework.com), is a free, open source framework for building mobile apps.

Ionic, the platform (ionic.io), is a platform that provides services and tools for Ionic apps and is not necessarily free.

Development of the framework is likely supported by Ionic.io but not exclusively since it is on Github. Both domains are owned by the same person.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it.